# How many ways can they travel?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 8 students and 2 cars, A car can have 5 seat & B car can have 4 seat,

How many ways are possible they can travel

Comment: You haven't provided any context - seems you _crafted_ the question for us, rather than you having real trouble.

Comment: not crafted its from GRE practice problems..

Comment: But still, what have you tried?

Comment: i used total!/in!(total - in)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways.

$5$ people on the first car and $3$ on the second car

or

$4$ persons each car.

You cannot choose more than $5$ people for the first car or more than $4$ for the second, so there are two only ways in which they can distribute.

Comment: nicely explained thank you :)

Comment: 8C5 + 8C4..is this possible?

Comment: @Saurabh I don't understand. The total amount of people is $8$. Given that one car can contain at most $5$ people and the other $4$, you have:

$5+3$ or $4+4$. All the other possibilities are... not possible.

Comment: ..sorry actually i was asking about arrangements

Comment: order doesnt matter

Answer (score 1):

You have two cases: One when there's an empty seat in car A and one where there is an empty seat in car B.

For the first case choose $5$ of the $8$ students and place them in car A, while the rest go in car $B$. For the second choose $4$ and place them in car A, while the rest in car $B$. At the end sum the combinations from the two cases.

Comment: excellent thank you :)

Comment: 8C5 + 8C4..is this possible?

Comment: @Saurabh Yes, that should be your answer.

Comment: but question is not for arrangements

Comment: @Saurabh Sorry, but I didn't get your point. The answer is alright given the question.

Comment: the point is there are two ways as you said but 8C5 + 8C4 will be true if same question ask for arrangement,right?

Comment: @Saurabh If the order of the people in the car doesn't matter then this is your answer. I mean it doesn't matter how they sit, what is important is in which car the students sits. Otherwise the answer would be different.